# Google Chart HTML Tooltip displays html text

Tags: html, charts, tooltip, google-visualization, dataview

I've specified HTML toolips in the options, but it still renders the HTML text in the tooltip instead of the result of the HTML. How can I fix this so that it renders the HTML result?

I create a data view and set the columns like so:

```
projectView.setColumns([0,1,3,{
    type:'string',
    role:'tooltip',
    calc:function(dt,row){
        var date = dt.getFormattedValue(row,0);
        var totalErrors = dt.getFormattedValue(row,3);
        var percent = Math.round((dt.getValue(row,3)/dt.getValue(row,1))*100);  
        return '<div><b>'+ date +'</b><br><b>Error Percent: </b>' + percent + '<br><b>Total Errors: </b>' + totalErrors + '</div>';
    }
}]);
```

And the options are like this:

```
var options = {
    width:850,
    height:375,
    chartArea: {width: '70%', height: '70%',left: 40,top:25},
    hAxis:{format:'MM/dd/yy'},
    vAxis:{logScale:false},         
    series:{0:{type:'line'},1:{type:'area'}},
    tooltip: { isHtml: true }};
```

Then I draw the chart:

```
var projectChart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('project_chart_div'));
projectChart.draw(projectView, options);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the `html` property as `true` in the calculated column for the view:

```
projectView.setColumns([0,1,3,{
    type:'string',
    role:'tooltip',
    properties: {
        html: true
    },
    calc:function(dt,row){
        var date = dt.getFormattedValue(row,0);
        var totalErrors = dt.getFormattedValue(row,3);
        var percent = Math.round((dt.getValue(row,3)/dt.getValue(row,1))*100);  
        return '<div><b>'+ date +'</b><br><b>Error Percent: </b>' + percent + '<br><b>Total Errors: </b>' + totalErrors + '</div>';
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I was fighting to resolve this issue, but I couldn't find this option "properties: { html: true } " anywhere. 
Not even here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content

I was using "p: {html: true}" but that not worked for me. You saved my day.