# google line chart tool-tips with multiple column data

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I have a line chart that shows 2 lines: one represents a date range with values and the other line is the previous period(also dates) with the previous values.

I want to show the relevant date and the value in the tool-tips for each line.

the tool-tips will look like this:

[image]

this is what i have right now:

```
function drawChart(chartData, elemId, chartWidth, chartHeight, startDate, endDate) {
    var chartToDraw = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     chartToDraw.addColumn('date', 'Date');
     chartToDraw.addColumn('number', 'Value');
     chartToDraw.addColumn({
         type: 'string',
         role: 'tooltip',
         properties: {
             html: true
         },
         calc: function (dt, row) { //doesn't get called for some reason
            var date = dt.getValue(row, 2);
            var val = dt.getValue(row, 1);
            return '<div>' + date + ' </br><b>value:</b>' + val + '</div>';
         }
     });
     chartToDraw.addColumn('number', 'Previous value');
     chartToDraw.addColumn({
         type: 'string',
         role: 'tooltip',
         properties: {
             html: true
         },
         calc: function (dt, row) { //doesn't get called for some reason
             var date = dt.getValue(row, 4);
             var val = dt.getValue(row, 3);
             return '<div>' + date + ' </br><b>value:</b>' + val + '</div>';
            }
        });

        if (chartData['dataPoints'] != undefined) {
            var currentDataArr = [];
            for (var point in chartData['dataPoints']) {
                currentDataArr.push([
                    chartData['dataPoints'][point].date,
                    chartData['dataPoints'][point].value,
                    chartData['dataPoints'][point].date,
                    chartData['dataPoints'][point].prevValue,
                    chartData['dataPoints'][point].prevDate
                ]);
            }
        }
        chartToDraw.addRows(currentDataArr);



    var timeFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
        pattern: "MMM dd"
    });
    timeFormatter.format(chartToDraw, 0);
    timeFormatter.format(chartToDraw, 2);
    timeFormatter.format(chartToDraw, 4);

    var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        'width': chartWidth,
        'height': chartHeight,
        pointSize: 4,
        colors: ['#0289cb', '#01af8a'],
        tooltip: {
            isHtml: true
        },
        chartArea: {
            width: '80%'
        },
        hAxis: {
            slantedText: true,
            slantedTextAngle: 30,
            viewWindow: {
                min: startDate,
                max: endDate
            },
            gridlines: {
                count: -1,
                units: {
                    days: {format: ['MMM dd']},
                    hours: {format: ['HH:mm', 'ha']}
                }
            },
            minorGridlines: {
                units: {
                    hours: {format: ['hh:mm:ss a', 'ha']},
                    minutes: {format: ['HH:mm a Z', ':mm']}
                }
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            viewWindow: {
                min: 0
            }
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(elemId));
    chart.draw(chartToDraw, options);
}
```

The problem is that all i see right now on the tool-tips is just the correct dates and i'm missing the value.
I'm not sure why the `calc` functions arn't being called, if i change the tool-tip's type to `string` i just get a `mismatch type` error.

Here is what i've looked at so far:

[Google Chart HTML Tooltip displays html text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860873/google-chart-html-tooltip-displays-html-text)

[Add tooltips to a Google Line Chart with multiple data series - with simplified test case and screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924826/add-tooltips-to-a-google-line-chart-with-multiple-data-series-with-simplified)

but all the changes i did to resamble those answers failed.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated columns only work with the [DataView Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView)
Not the [DataTable Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable)...

To use, load your DataTable first, then create the DataView
Use [setColumns](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView_setColumns) to add your tooltips...

Drawing from the question, it might look something like this...

```
var chartToDraw = new google.visualization.DataTable();
chartToDraw.addColumn('date', 'Date');
chartToDraw.addColumn('number', 'Value');
chartToDraw.addColumn('number', 'Previous value');
chartToDraw.addColumn('date', 'Previous Date');

if (chartData['dataPoints'] != undefined) {
    var currentDataArr = [];
    for (var point in chartData['dataPoints']) {
        currentDataArr.push([
            chartData['dataPoints'][point].date,
            chartData['dataPoints'][point].value,
            chartData['dataPoints'][point].prevValue,
            chartData['dataPoints'][point].prevDate
        ]);
    }
}
chartToDraw.addRows(currentDataArr);

// create view over data, set columns
var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(chartToDraw);
dataView.setColumns([0, 1,
  {
    type: 'string',
    role: 'tooltip',
    properties: {
      html: true
    },
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var date = dt.getValue(row, 0);
      var val = dt.getValue(row, 1);
      return '<div>' + date + ' </br><b>value:</b>' + val + '</div>';
    }
  },
  2,
  {
    type: 'string',
    role: 'tooltip',
    properties: {
      html: true
    },
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var date = dt.getValue(row, 3);
      var val = dt.getValue(row, 2);
      return '<div>' + date + ' </br><b>value:</b>' + val + '</div>';
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: thanks! this helps a lot, i'm just missing the `prevDate`, I added it as another column, added `3,` after the `2,` in the second tool-tip and changed to `var date = dt.getValue(row, 3);`, but i'm getting an error: `All series on a given axis must be of the same data type`, any idea how to solve that?

Comment: yes, the second date is throwing things off. if you include two dates in the data, you have to use two axis'... do you want to plot the previous value on a second axis using previous date? or plot the previous value on the current date's axis and only show previous date in tooltip? if the latter, add previous date to the data table, do not include as own column in data view, simply reference in tooltip... (see edit)

Comment: I need to plot the previous value on the current date's axis and only show previous date on the tool-tip, so i added the column as you did, I added the data just as you did and removed the `3` from the data view and just used the reference in the tooltip but i get the same error as before

Comment: and you're using the view to draw the chart, not the table? --> `chart.draw(dataView, options);`

Comment: Yes! that did it! it works! thanks a lot! I just had to change  `var date = dt.getValue(row, 3);` to --> `var date = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 3);` so it would parse the date with my `timeFormatter`